# C# Console Application - Edit User Setting at runtime

Tags: c#, console-application

I had a Winforms App with a propertyGrid to let the user edit his settings.
How to achieve the same goal whithin a Console Application?

**ANSWER**
Thanks to those who answered. 
Here is a synthetic code based on a few answers :

```
Console.WriteLine("Choose user settings to setup");
Console.WriteLine("User setting1: press 1");
Console.WriteLine("User setting2: press 2");

string line = Console.ReadLine();
int code = int.Parse(line);
swicth(code) 
{
   case 1: 
    Settings.Default.MyProperty = line ;
    Settings.Default.Save();
    break;

   case 2: 
    ...
 }
```

Comment: @mizipzor : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx

Comment: DOWNVOTING WITH NO COMMENTS IS SOOOO LAAAAAAAAAAAAME :-((((((((((

Comment: i would guess that the initial downvotes were due to quite a vague initial question. i want to point out that although youve got your answer and the downvotes have been balanced i suggest editing your question, losing your temper in all-caps is never good.

Comment: @mizipzor Sorry. I've edited my question back. You're right. However, I expect people to comment and leave a chance to edit/give details before downvoting abruptly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Settings.Default.MyProperty1 = "some value";
Settings.Default.MyProperty2 = 2;
Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: Yeah thank you for you support that's the trick. After being humiliated by the downvotes I found out that on my own.

Answer (score 2):

You should prompt the user about user settings. Something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Choose user settings to setup");
Console.WriteLine("User setting1: press 1");
Console.WriteLine("User setting2: press 2");
....
...
string line = Console.ReadLine();
int code = int.Parse(line);
swicth(code) 
{
   case 1: 
     ....
    .....
   case 2: 
}
```

After save changes in `XML` file.

If it's **not** you're asking for, please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Console applications does not have an User Interface, by definition (though you can force display of Windows Forms). You need to rethink your solution. Maybe you want to use app.config (XYZ.exe.config) or a separate configuration file. BTW, you can edit application settings file from code.

Comment: While I would argue about console applications "not having a user interface" (in fact they do: the console!). +1 for suggesting using a configuration file instead, which is usually sufficient for a console application (at least a start-process-exit-style one).

Comment: I Know that thank you for the precision. I don't care what is the default, I am goal-oriented and I do what it takes to achieve it and think out of the box. I do NOT want to use a separate file, to be edited, and I was after some smart way to make the user edit all settins without the need of doing this one by one (see edit). Anyway, forget it... THnak you.